# Leitura de arquivo CSV e armazenamento dos dados em um vetor

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

estou com a seguinte dificuldade: preciso ler os dados que estão dentro de um arquivo CSV e armazenar em um array para realizar cálculos com tais dados, porém não sei como fazê-lo. Estou usando Python 3.6. Agradeço desde já.

Meu código está assim:
import csv

```
with open("arquivo.CSV") as arquivocsv:
    ler = csv.DictReader(arquivocsv, delimiter=",")
    for linha in ler:
        print(linha)
```

O que eu preciso é ler o arquivo csv que contém 6 colunas com os dados necessários e armazenar em 6 arrays/listas diferentes, um para cada coluna, para assim realizar os cálculos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dados = {} 
with open("arquivo.CSV") as arquivocsv:
    ler = csv.DictReader(arquivocsv, delimiter=",")
    for linha in ler:
        for chave, valor in linha.items():
            if chave not in dados:
                 dados[chave] = []
            dados[chave].append(valor)
```

Não é tão difícil assim. 
Essa forma é boa para quem não conhece Python e fica bem legível. COm uma equipe mais experiente, você pode usar o método `setdefault` dos dicionários: eles já te devolvem um novo valor se não houver um - assim, você economiza duas linhas:

```
dados = {} 
with open("arquivo.CSV") as arquivocsv:
    ler = csv.DictReader(arquivocsv, delimiter=",")
    for linha in ler:
        for chave, valor in linha.items():
            dados.setdefault(chave, []).append(valor))
```