# Como utilizar Python integrado com .CSV

Tags: python, csv, integração

Bom dia. Tenho que ler um campo(linha) de um arquivo em .csv e preencher um determinado campo no sistema. Como devo fazer? Exemplo, meu .csv é massa de dados para o preenchimento de um cadastro.

Comment: Relacionado: [Leitura de arquivo CSV e armazenamento dos dados em um vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/leitura-de-arquivo-csv-e-armazenamento-dos-dados-em-um-vetor)

Comment: Também leia [Como ler um arquivo CSV em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97269/como-ler-um-arquivo-csv-em-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode fazer de varias formas, mas a mais usual e:

```
import csv
with open('214385.csv') as f:
   f_csv = csv.reader(f)
   headers = next(f_csv)
   for row in f_csv:
   # Process row
      print(row)
```

link: https://github.com/weltonvaz/stackoverflow/blob/master/214385.py

Exemplo de arquivo csv:

obs: a primeira linha e de cabeçalho

```
Symbol,Price,Date,Time,Change,Volume
"AA",39.48,"6/11/2007","9:36am",-0.18,181800
"AIG",71.38,"6/11/2007","9:36am",-0.15,195500
"AXP",62.58,"6/11/2007","9:36am",-0.46,935000
"BA",98.31,"6/11/2007","9:36am",+0.12,104800
"C",53.08,"6/11/2007","9:36am",-0.25,360900
"CAT",78.29,"6/11/2007","9:36am",-0.23,225400
```

link: https://github.com/weltonvaz/stackoverflow/blob/master/214385.csv

este exemplo foi tirado do livro: Python Cookbook --> http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch06.html#_solution_94

Comment: Welton, boa tarde. Obrigado na resposta. Tenho o seguinte codigo:
Click("132356.png")
type("Aqui tenho que colocar as informações do .csv") Como fazer esta arte?

Comment: Não entendi, vc poderia explicar melhor.